# How to change the background or foreground color of the visual studio 2010 tooltip

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I need to change the tooltip in visual studio 2010 when you hover your mouse over a code item when not debugging.

[image]

Obviously I am trying to theme my VS to be dark, but I cant seem to change this setting.

I have Powertools, Visual Assist X and Color Theme editor installed.

I can rule out Color Theme editor colors because it has a global edit function where I can make every setting black and it does not change.

I have tried

```
Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Signature Help Tooltip Background
```

It has no effect.

The foreground text is derived from windows window text color (i cant change this in windows as my theme relies on it)

Other tooltips in VS look fine

Solution explorer:

[image]

Parameter help is OK because the forecolor is darker:

[image]

It appears to be a WPF brush which gives me the impression that I cant change it with a simple color setting.

I would be happy with either background or foreground color change.

Answer (score 1):

I no longer have 2010, but in 2013 you change foreground here
[Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Editor Tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYsqF.png)

Maybe its similar in 2010?