# How to set editor tooltip color and background in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-editor

i am using black scheme and set up color setting for editor tooltips: [image: Visual Studio 2010 Color options settings]
Sample preview is correct but actual result is different:
[image: Visual Studio 2010 Edit window with tooltip]

Is it possible to set up tooltip colors in Visual Studio 2010 properly?

Comment: GOD I WISH you had an answer to this question. This would CHANGE MY LIFE.

Comment: FWIW, I walked through adjusting this setting just now.   Seems the first time you set it, nothing happens.  I had to open the settings window a second time, put the same settings in, and then they worked.   Maybe that's the same issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Productivity Power Tools and following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053158/visual-studio-2010-themes-change-parameter-help-background-color) it is at least possible to read the signatures again, but [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564988/how-to-change-the-background-or-foreground-color-of-the-visual-studio-2010-toolti) gives me little hope how to fix the other color settings.

Edit: Installing CSharpIntellisencePresenter makes the Auto-Complete readable in a dark theme, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999407/how-to-change-visual-studio-2010-intellisense-context-menu-highlight-color)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Hack-It to enable the "Custom..." buttons with VS2008 and changed color settings were saved (still present after a VS restart).

But I was not changing the colors for the correct item I guess.
I am using Visual Assist and I think the 'Editor Tooltip' is not the item I want to change the colors from.

You could give it a try...

Anyone knows from which item I must change colors to affect Visual Assist tool tips when hovering a function ?

---

For Visual Assist tooltip I need to change Windows theme...